# Number of queries in wordpress

Tags: optimization

I have 870 queries in 3,216 seconds. Is that normal? What are that queries? How can I reduce that queries? What is number of normal queries.

Custom Page: 870 queries in 3,216 seconds.

Home Page: 866 queries in 2,296 seconds.

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers from?

Comment: with <?php echo get_num_queries(); ?> queries in <?php timer_stop(1); ?>  that

Comment: Actually there is no 'normal' but it would be (*recommended*) smart to reduce that number to below 100 (or even less).  Most servers will need a lot of cpu power and memory when you have that many request (not even talking about a busy server). You are doing some wrong imho when you think you need to diplay a page/post with such an amount of queries.

Comment: it is cause of shortcodes. how can I cache them? @Charles